# Configuring ESXi server to produce same performance results

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, esxi

I have an ESXi 5.5.0 server with a single VM. When I run some benchmark on the VM there are 6% differences between times of different runs on the VM (each run around 250 seconds).
When I've run such tests on clean hardware (no virtualizations) the difference between measurements was 1%.
Are there any settings which may help making the VM performance more predictable?
The guest OS is linux.
The tests is a complete server setup with Solr, Postgres and java server and contains lots of CPU usage and IO too.
I've already tried making the disk thick zero eager type which didn't help.
**Important note: The ESXi is running only one VM. So resources are exactly the same between runs.**

Comment: What sorts of tests? What sort of load is the server under? As a standalone hypervisor, how is your host os linux?

Comment: Added tests description @Journeyman Geek

Comment: @AvnerLevy, you can't expect consistent performance in virtual machine. Do not forget you have in lower level a hypervisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the following settings of the VM:
1. Changed disk to thick eager zeroed
2. Resources-> CPU -> reservation = max
3. Resources-> Memory -> Reserve all guest memory
4. Resources-> Disk -> Shared = high
5. Resources-> Advance CPU -> Hyperthread code sharing= none

Then the differences between the different tests were around 1%.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. That way it will no longer be in the list of unaswered, sometimes bumped questions.